C# stack trace, what does (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) mean?
This might be a very simple (beginner) question, but i'm coming up emtpy, Google doesn't help me...
I'm trying to figure out a stacktrace for a C#/Android application I don't have the source from.
Specifically, what does '(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)' mean?
Does this mean the application is doing something with System.Runtime.Remoting?
Tried stackoverflow, Google, dotnet docs. Tried some mockup programs to match stacktraces. No luck
